# Can I prepopluate an iframe with content from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a JavaScript function that does a combination of AJAX and string manipulation to produce a full HTML page as a string. I.e.:

```
var markup='<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>';
```

That is very simplified and I cannot guarantee that the HTML structure is predictable. How can I display that content on the page? I think an `iframe` makes the most sense since string contains a full HTML page but I don't know how to inject the markup into the iframe.

I don't want to create another physical file just to use as a "proxy" so I am hoping for a solution that can be encompassed entirely in one HTML page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
var doc = iframe.contentDocument; // a about:blank
doc.open();
doc.write(htmlstring);
doc.close();
```

works for me. I also did use `<object>`s with a data-uri in their `data` attribute, e.g. to display xml documents:

```
var object = document.createElement("object");
object.setAttribute('data', "data:text/xml, "+xmlstring);
```

You also can use a `<object data="about:blank">` instead of the iframe to get a contentDocument to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can change html of an iframe from jQuery like this

```
function get_me_html(){
    return '<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>'
}

$('iframe').contents().find('html').html(get_me_html())
```

see this in action here http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/Kegc3/7/

Comment: This worked, almost. I saw it flicker and then disappear. Then the iframe was blank. I suspect that some other js function may have been interfering but I didn't troubleshoot too much because Bergi's answer worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

forget the iframe, look up [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and trim the head out.

Comment: I tried this first but I was experiencing unusual problems. Wrapping the markup in the jQuery object was returning an array instead of a dom element. Thats probably another SE question though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like jQuery thickbox which can create an modal child window inside your HTML document and do things somewhat like what you're looking for but yes for that you will have to dump your contents inside a DIV which you can create on the fly.

See if below post helps:
http://blogs.digitss.com/technology/hacking-jquery-thickbox/

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you could just do this:

```
var markup='<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>';
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').html(markup);
```

Or, if you can strip out the tags you don't want:

```
markup = markup.replace(/(</?html>|</?body>)/gi, "");
$('#divId').html(markup);
```

***NOTE: I have no idea what the input HTML looks like, so make sure you can actually strip out the HTML before running this code. This is an example to help you get started.***

This is using a DIV like this:

```
<div id="divId">Content will go here</div>
```

Comment: -1 for "parsing" html with regex. Plus, your attempt won't trim tags like head, meta,title ...etc

Comment: Notice I said "if you can." This is just an example. I have no idea what the requirements of his application are.

Comment: I tried `$('#iframe').html(markup)` but the iframe just remained empty. Is it supposed to be able to work like that?

Comment: Sorry, I left off the `.contents().find('body')` part. It's now in there.